# Nativescript - publish to app store Incorrect Verification Code?

Tags: ios, nativescript, app-store-connect

I am trying to publish my app to appstore connect with the following command tns publish ios 'aaaaaa@bbb.ccc' 'dasdhasldasjdl' --bundle --env.* --appleApplicationSpecificPassword 'pdnlaksndi2dasd' and I get an sms with the code. Once I enter it in the console, i get the following:

```
    {
  "service_errors" : [ {
    "code" : "-21669",
    "title" : "Incorrect Verification Code",
    "message" : "Incorrect verification code.",
    "suppressDismissal" : false
  } ],
  "hasError" : true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?